# working with android 9 patch file not working

Tags: android, nine-patch

[image]

I have been trying to change the color of the gray that surrounds my custom tabs, I have tried looking for the answer on YouTube:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfrXE2R2nqM

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMWlRXfKgtY

This helped me understand the process of 9-patch files but I must be doing something wrong for this not to work.

What I have tried doing so far:

1. In my project I see in the "Package Explorer" I see Android 4.1, which is in ...android-sdk/platforms/android-16.  I opened that with winrar, went into res/drawable-mdpi and just to see if anything would change I replaced "tab_selected.9.png" and "tab_selected_v4.9.png" with the image of "tab_pressed.9.png".  I then tried to compile my project just to see the same gray for the background of my tab buttons.
2. The current android project I am working on I placed the changed "tab_selected.9.png" and "tab_selected_v4.9.png" inside of my drawables folder and tried running it just to see the same thing.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, am I not compiling something or do I need to mess with different .9.png files?  Or does anyone have a simple process just to change the gray color of these tabs?  I guess the quick answer for me here is what would I have to do to get the image of "tab_pressed.9.png" to replace "tab_selected.9.png"

EDIT:

tab_selected.9.png

[image]
tab_pressed.9.png

[image]

Comment: Could you share your 9 patch images? Is grey color part of your tab images?

Comment: Also, 9-patching won't change colors. It just tells Android how to scale the images and the view's content

Comment: @Gagan What I have basically did at this point is I have not created any new 9-patch images I just took the image of "tab_pressed.9.png" and made 2 copies of that and called them "tab_selected.9.png" and "tab_selected_v4.9.png" and inside of the android.jar I replaced those 2 images with the image of "tab_pressed.9.png".

Comment: @JoePlante But when I press on a tab, that same color matches the color on "tab_pressed.9.png" so it must match to that .9.png.

Comment: The 9 patch image *may* not work this way. It would be useful if you can share the 9-patch image you are using in your project.

Comment: @Gagan They are the defaulted .9.png images, I have not created any new ones.  But give me one second and I will try to put them as an EDIT section to the post.

Comment: 9-patches seems ok. Did you try cleaning the whole project and building it again? It worked for me once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little tricky. Sometimes the stuff like the grey can creep in from the underlying Android layer. Sometimes things like tabhost have views that have to be overridden. I remember having to maek a selector drawable in XML to get the tabhost to work with custom items.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the only pixels in the border are the 9-patch ones, either black (#f000 in ARGB) or fully transparent (#0000).
It's a normal to left some pixels with some transparency on those pixels that gets unnoticed at simple view.